# Updating objects of key array pairs without mutation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I used this code snippet inside one of my useEffect hooks. But it mutates the object and shows me the message to be appeared twice.

```
setConversations((prev) => {
  const oldConversation = room in prev ? prev[room] : [];
  const newConversation = [
    ...oldConversation,
    {
      sender: from,
      message: msg,
      time: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    },
  ];
  return { ...prev, [room]: newConversation };
});
```

What am I missing? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Edit:

The custom effect (where the message is received):

```
export const useSocketEventListener = (
  socket,
  peer,
  setPeersOnConference,
  setPeerIdsOnConference,
  setAvailableUsers,
  availableRooms,
  setAvailableRooms,
  setConferenceId,
  setCallOthersTriggered,
  setTransited,
  calls,
  setCalls,
  setConversations
) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    socket?.on('receiveMessage', (msg, from, room) => {
      // alert(`${msg} from ${from} room ${room}`);
      // let temp = socket.id === room ? from : room;
      setConversations((prev) => { // called twice (expected once to add the message to the state)
        const oldConversation = room in prev ? prev[room] : [];
        const newConversation = [
          ...oldConversation,
          {
            sender: from,
            message: msg,
            time: new Date().toLocaleString(),
          },
        ];
        console.log('calling once');
        return { ...prev, [room]: newConversation };
      });
      console.log('i fire once');
    });
    socket?.on('joinRoomAlert', (socketId, room) => {
      //
    });
    socket?.on('leaveRoomAlert', (socketId, room) => {
      alert(`${socketId} left the room ${room}`);
    });
    socket?.on('receivePeersOnConference', (peersOnConference) => {
      // setPeersOnConference(peersOnConference);
    });
    socket?.on('receiveData', (data) => {
      setAvailableUsers(data.users);
      setAvailableRooms(data.rooms);
    });
    socket?.on('peerEndCall', (peerId) => {
      calls[peerId]?.close();
      setCalls((prev) =>
        Object.keys(prev)
          .filter((key) => key !== peerId)
          .reduce((obj, key) => ({ ...obj, [key]: prev[key] }), {})
      );
      setPeersOnConference((prev) => {
        if (Object.keys(prev).length === 1) {
          setCallOthersTriggered(false);
          setTransited(false);
          return {};
        }
        return Object.keys(prev)
          .filter((key) => key !== peerId)
          .reduce((obj, key) => ({ ...obj, [key]: prev[key] }), {});
      });
    });
    socket?.on(
      'receiveCallOthersTriggered',
      (peerIds, conferenceId, caller) => {
        console.log('peerIds: ', peerIds);
        setConferenceId(socket.id === conferenceId ? caller : conferenceId);
        setCallOthersTriggered(true);
        setPeerIdsOnConference([...peerIds]);
      }
    );
    socket?.on('leaveCallAlert', (leftPeerId) => {
      //
    });
    socket?.emit('fetchData');
    peer?.on('call', async (call) => {
      try {
        setTransited(true);
        const selfStream = await getMedia();
        console.log(peer.id, selfStream);
        setPeersOnConference((prev) => ({ ...prev, [peer.id]: selfStream }));
        call.answer(selfStream);
        call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
          console.log(call.peer, remoteStream);
          setPeersOnConference((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [call.peer]: remoteStream,
          }));
        });
        call.on('close', () => {
          selfStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
        });
        call.on('error', (e) => console.log('error in peer call'));
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error while receiving call');
      }
    });
  }, [socket, peer]);
};
```

The function to send message:

```
export const sendMessage = (socket, msg, to, setMessage, setConversations) => {
  socket.emit('sendMessage', msg, to);
  setMessage('');
  setConversations((prev) => { // called once
    const oldConversation = to in prev ? prev[to] : [];
    const newConversation = [
      ...oldConversation,
      {
        sender: socket.id,
        message: msg,
        time: new Date().toLocaleString(),
      },
    ];
    return { ...prev, [to]: newConversation };
  });
};
```

**Note:** Used the custom hook in the App.js file.

Comment: @emeraldsanto according to the suggestion you provided, the 'i got fire' message triggers twice but there is only one component I used. Could you please explain the second method he mentioned about? And another question, is my setState function mutating the object or not?

Comment: The problem in this case is further down in the solution, see "React Strict Mode" which causes effects to run twice in development. As for mutations, no you code is not mutating anything because you're spreading all references to arrays and objects into new ones.

Comment: I disabled the strict mode and still adding the message to the state twice. What could be other issues?

Comment: We would need to see the `useEffect` definition and other relevant code to be able to tell.

Comment: I edited the question. Now hopefully you'll find it helpful to go through the problem.

Comment: Unsubscribe the socket listeners in a  `useEffect` hook cleanup function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling for a while, I found a hack to handle double render in useEffect logic. There may exist other ways to solve my specific problem but the hack I found will do fine for me.
As react-18 renders the useEffect hook twice in development mode, disabling the strict mode won't make the render once. For which we need to use a boolean variable to handle such cases.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let ignore = false;
  fetchStuff().then(res => {
    if (!ignore) setResult(res)
  })
  return () => { ignore = true }
}, [])
```

For more details, check out [this](https://medium.com/geekculture/the-tricky-behavior-of-useeffect-hook-in-react-18-282ef4fb570a) blog post.

**Note:** The main problem was not about mutation. Updating function is working totally fine. Rendering the useEffect twice caused the error to be occured. :)